# Bind multiple images to gridview column based on ID

Tags: asp.net

In my project gridview column i need to display multiple images based on Id which is suplied by database.
I used templte field to display images on grid below but not showing any image on the grid.

Please can any one help me.\

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemStyle Width="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<ItemTemplate>
     <a href="#" id="lnkAssetTypeIndicator" 
        title="View/Edit Asset Details" 
        onclick="return LoadAssetDetails('<%# Eval("AssetId") %>', 0)">
              <%# (Eval("AssetTypeIndicator").ToString() != "1" ? 
                   "<img border='0' src='Images/AssetType_' " + Eval("AssetTypeId") + " '.png' >" 
                                                                : "")%>
     </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

can we bind image in the runtime? Please provide code for or site to display image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# (Eval("AssetTypeIndicator")).ToString() != "1" ? 
      "<img border='0' src='Images/AssetType_" + Eval("AssetTypeId") + ".png' />" : "")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to supply the image ID and the path.

```
       <img id="imgsome" alt="My Images" src="/ImagePath/<%#Eval("ID")%>"/>
```